# How to use GTMetrix Api using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, api, gtmetrix

I am new to API usage. I have properly managed to utilize Google Page Insights V.5 API through javascript code, but I cannot for the life of me succeed in doing so for GTMetrix. It seems the only information relating to GTMetrix API & Javascript is a link to the RapidApi website. I simply wish to achieve the same simple retrieval of data from GTMetrix as I have from Google. Is this possible?

Am I simply structuring my request incorrectly when I set it as:

```
https://gtmetrix.com/api/0.1/?login-user=myemail@email.com&login-pass=MyRanDomApIKeY&location=2&url=https://sitetotest.com
```

Because when I set my Google Page Insights Request URL as the following it works.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=https://websitetotest.com&category=performance&strategy=desktop&key=MyRanDomApIKeY
```

The below code works for Google Page Insights and I am even able to retrieve JSON data in a browser window with a URL such as:

```
<div id="firstmetric"></div>
<br>
<div id="domSize"></div>

<button>Click Me</button>

<script>
$('button').click(function(){

var baseUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=";


var fieldUrl = "https://websitetotest.com";
var trailing = "&category=performance&strategy=desktop&key=MyRanDomApIKeY";

$.getJSON(baseUrl + fieldUrl + trailing, function(data){

console.log(data);

var item = data.lighthouseResult.categories.performance.auditRefs[0].weight;
var domSize = data.lighthouseResult.audits['dom-size'].displayValue;



$("#firstmetric").html( item );

$("#domSize").html( domSize );

});

});
```

I truly need it spelled out for me because anything less is going to lead me to ask follow up questions and put us in a tail spin. :/

As a newbie, JSFiddle has been a life saving resource for testing and trying, breaking, and building in my learning process. If it wouldn't be too much to ask for, a fiddle would help me get my brain around things.

Answer (score 1):

The parameters that you are using: `login-user` and `login-pass` refer to HTTP authentication on the *page you are analyzing* (as in, GTmetrix will pass these parameters on your analysis) not your GTmetrix API credentials.

The authentication used for the GTmetrix API is your e-mail for the username and your API key as the password, as pointed out [by the API docs](https://gtmetrix.com/api/).

Another thing to keep in mind is that GTmetrix will not allow you to do API calls through your web application frontend, since they disallow [CORS requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). If you do it through your Web application on a normal website, you would be exposing your GTmetrix API key, which is probably not a good idea.

So, you would then do it through your backend code. For example if done through Node JavaScript:

```
fetch("https://gtmetrix.com/api/0.1/locations", {
    headers: new Headers({
        "Authorization": 'Basic ' + btoa("[YOUR E-MAIL]" + ":" +"[YOUR API KEY]"),
    }),
}).then(res => res.json())
.then(response => console.log(response));
```

would print me the array of locations.

Note that whichever backend code you choose, you need to add the basic authorization header request for you API call and encode it properly (that is what the btoa function call does).